# Is my used phone rooted? What threats can I be at risk of? What can I do about it?

Tags: unrooting

I bought a used phone (Samsung Note 8) and soon began to suspect something wasn't right. I would often have to re-enter my password from lock screen, as if it had rebooted and other small oddities. Then, when I tried to use certain apps, I would get warnings or denied access, saying my phone is 'rooted'.
I hadn't heard of this before.

Following advice from a repair shop and what I've been able to find online, I can provide these details:

2 factory resets have both failed to wipe any of my data (all pictures, video, etc untouched), as well as a number of suspicious apps.

Several root checking apps have all come back negative 'Not Rooted'. However, BusyBox and SuperUser are both detected and it fails SafetyNet test.

My device's Google Play Protection is not certified and when I attempted to register my GSF number with Google manually, it not only didn't work but displayed a completely different GSF than my own as being registered.

I don't know what to make of it all. I really hope one of you guys will recognise exactly what's going on and be able to advise.

Should I be worried? What should I do?

Thank you!

Comment: backup everything to PC and google drive, download ROM from samloader and flash it from Odin to unroot